# Gambas problems

Tags: gambas3

I tried to install "Gambas3" but it did not install properly. When I tried to use Gambas3 the program would not come up on the screen. Instead I see next to the Activities icon the Gambas3 name comes up along with the moving circle. Then the name and moving circle disappear.
It appears that the files are on the hard-drive. I then tried to remove Gambas3 but the computer said that Gambas3 was not installed. How can I can get rid of the icon and the program files? Thanks in advance.

Hi, I looked on the Gambas web site and found the same problem. The fix is to load the file gambas3-gb-util-web. Apparently the file was not installed when I downloaded using 'sudo apt install gambas3' command. It is now working properly. Thanks for all your help. -Peter

Comment: How did you install "Gambas3" ? Since you could not remove it, one has to assume that is hasn't been from the repository....

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: I installed the program as I have others.That is I used the "sudo apt install gambas3" in the terminal.

Comment: Run `gambas3` in the terminal. What is the output?

Comment: I get this message "unable to load componet: gb.util.web"

Comment: Please include errors etc in your question, and not in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to install an additional component

```
sudo apt install gambas3-gb-form-print
```

[Source](https://itsfoss.com/install-gambas-ubuntu/)